# Change css on button using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, chat, magnific-popup

I want to change the simple whatsapp green button to the glowing css nice button like this ----->>>

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.floatingWhatsApp = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            phone: '',
            message: '',
            size: '72px',
            backgroundColor: '#25D366',
            position: 'left',
            popupMessage: '',
            showPopup: false,
            showOnIE: true,
            autoOpenTimeout: 0,
            headerColor: '#128C7E',
            headerTitle: 'WhatsApp Chat',
            zIndex: 0,
            buttonImage: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 800 800" width="800" height="800"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_A3g8G5hPEGG2L0B6hFCxamU4cc8rfqzQ"><rect width="800" height="800"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_A3g8G5hPEGG2L0B6hFCxamU4cc8rfqzQ)"><g><path d=" M 787.59 800 L 12.41 800 C 5.556 800 0 793.332 0 785.108 L 0 14.892 C 0 6.667 5.556 0 12.41 0 L 787.59 0 C 794.444 0 800 6.667 800 14.892 L 800 785.108 C 800 793.332 794.444 800 787.59 800 Z " fill="rgb(37,211,102)"/></g><g><path d=" M 508.558 450.429 C 502.67 447.483 473.723 433.24 468.325 431.273 C 462.929 429.308 459.003 428.328 455.078 434.22 C 451.153 440.114 439.869 453.377 436.434 457.307 C 433 461.236 429.565 461.729 423.677 458.78 C 417.79 455.834 398.818 449.617 376.328 429.556 C 358.825 413.943 347.008 394.663 343.574 388.768 C 340.139 382.873 343.207 379.687 346.155 376.752 C 348.804 374.113 352.044 369.874 354.987 366.436 C 357.931 362.999 358.912 360.541 360.875 356.614 C 362.837 352.683 361.857 349.246 360.383 346.299 C 358.912 343.352 347.136 314.369 342.231 302.579 C 337.451 291.099 332.597 292.654 328.983 292.472 C 325.552 292.301 321.622 292.265 317.698 292.265 C 313.773 292.265 307.394 293.739 301.996 299.632 C 296.6 305.527 281.389 319.772 281.389 348.752 C 281.389 377.735 302.487 405.731 305.431 409.661 C 308.376 413.592 346.949 473.062 406.015 498.566 C 420.062 504.634 431.03 508.256 439.581 510.969 C 453.685 515.451 466.521 514.818 476.666 513.302 C 487.978 511.613 511.502 499.06 516.409 485.307 C 521.315 471.55 521.315 459.762 519.842 457.307 C 518.371 454.851 514.446 453.377 508.558 450.429 Z  M 401.126 597.117 L 401.047 597.117 C 365.902 597.104 331.431 587.661 301.36 569.817 L 294.208 565.572 L 220.08 585.017 L 239.866 512.743 L 235.21 505.332 C 215.604 474.149 205.248 438.108 205.264 401.1 C 205.307 293.113 293.17 205.257 401.204 205.257 C 453.518 205.275 502.693 225.674 539.673 262.696 C 576.651 299.716 597.004 348.925 596.983 401.258 C 596.939 509.254 509.078 597.117 401.126 597.117 Z  M 567.816 234.565 C 523.327 190.024 464.161 165.484 401.124 165.458 C 271.24 165.458 165.529 271.161 165.477 401.085 C 165.46 442.617 176.311 483.154 196.932 518.892 L 163.502 641 L 288.421 608.232 C 322.839 627.005 361.591 636.901 401.03 636.913 L 401.126 636.913 L 401.127 636.913 C 530.998 636.913 636.717 531.2 636.77 401.274 C 636.794 338.309 612.306 279.105 567.816 234.565" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"/></g></g></svg>',
        }, options);

        var isMobile = mobilecheck();

        //set the .floating-wpp default class
        this.addClass('floating-wpp');

        //#region jQuery Elements
        var $button = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $buttonImageContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $popup = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $header = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $popupMessage = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $btnSend = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $inputMessage = $(document.createElement('div'));
        //#endregion

        //#region Main Button
        $buttonImageContainer.addClass('floating-wpp-button-image');

        $button.addClass('floating-wpp-button')
            .append($(settings.buttonImage))
            .css({
                'width': settings.size,
                'height': settings.size,
                'background-color': settings.backgroundColor
            });

        if (!isInternetExplorer() || settings.showOnIE) {
            $button.append($buttonImageContainer).appendTo(this);
        }

        $button.on('click', function () {
            if (isMobile && settings.showPopup) {
                openPopup();
            }
            else {
                sendWhatsappMessage();
            }
        });
        //#endregion

        //#region Fake Chat Pop-up
        if (settings.showPopup) {
            var $textarea = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
            var $closeBtn = $(document.createElement('strong'));
            var $sendIcon = $('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 20 18" width="20" height="18"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_fgX00hLzP9PnAfCkGQoSPsYB7aEGkj1G"><rect width="20" height="18"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_fgX00hLzP9PnAfCkGQoSPsYB7aEGkj1G)"><path d=" M 0 0 L 0 7.813 L 16 9 L 0 10.188 L 0 18 L 20 9 L 0 0 Z " fill="rgb(46,46,46)"/></g></svg>')

            $popup.addClass('floating-wpp-popup');
            $header.addClass('floating-wpp-head');
            $popupMessage.addClass('floating-wpp-message');
            $inputMessage.addClass('floating-wpp-input-message');
            $btnSend.addClass('floating-wpp-btn-send');

            $popupMessage.text(settings.popupMessage);
            $textarea.val(settings.message);

            if (!settings.popupMessage) {
                $popupMessage.hide();
            }

            $header.append('<span>' + settings.headerTitle + '</span>', $closeBtn)
                .css('background-color', settings.headerColor);

            $btnSend.append($sendIcon);
            $inputMessage.append($textarea, $btnSend);

            $closeBtn.addClass('close').html('&times;');

            $popup.append(
                $header,
                $popupMessage,
                $inputMessage)
                .appendTo(this);

            $popupMessage.click(function () {
                //sendWhatsappMessage();
            });

            $closeBtn.click(function () {
                //popup.removeClass('active');
            });

            $header.click(function () {
                $popup.removeClass('active');
            });

            $textarea.keypress(function (event) {
                settings.message = $(this).val();

                if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey && !isMobile) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $btnSend.click();
                }
            });

            $btnSend.click(function () {
                settings.message = $textarea.val();
                sendWhatsappMessage();
            });

            this.mouseenter(function () {
                openPopup();
            });

            if (settings.autoOpenTimeout > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    openPopup();
                }, settings.autoOpenTimeout);
            }

            function openPopup() {
                if (!$popup.hasClass('active')) {
                    $popup.addClass('active');
                    $textarea.focus();
                }
            }
        }

        if (settings.zIndex) {
            $(this).css('z-index', settings.zIndex);
        }

        if (settings.position === 'right') {
            this.css({
                left: 'auto',
                right: '15px'
            });
            $popup.css('right', '0');
        }
        //#endregion

        function sendWhatsappMessage() {
            var apilink = 'http://';

            apilink += isMobile ? 'api' : 'web';
            apilink += '.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + settings.phone + '&text=' + encodeURI(settings.message);

            window.open(apilink);
        }
    }

    function isInternetExplorer() {
        var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
        return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0 || userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
    }

    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function (a) { if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true; })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
        return check;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.floating-wpp {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: bottom 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.4);
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button img,
.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.floating-wpp:hover {
    bottom: 17px;
}

.floating-wpp:hover .floating-wpp-button {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.4);
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup {
    /*border: 2px solid white;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #E5DDD5;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.25);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: bottom 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup.active {
    padding: 0 12px 12px 12px;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 82px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup .floating-wpp-message {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup.active .floating-wpp-message {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup .floating-wpp-head {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 -15px 10px -15px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-input-message {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px -15px -15px -15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-input-message textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    resize: none;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-btn-send {
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Floating WhatsApp Button Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="floating-wpp.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="floating-wpp.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myButton"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myButton').floatingWhatsApp({
            phone: '5491133359850',
            popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?',
            message: "I'd like to ...",
            showPopup: true,
            showOnIE: false,
            headerTitle: 'WhatsApp!',
            headerColor: 'green',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            buttonImage: '<img src="wha.png" />'
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to change the aspect of the button to an glowin css button like this one
but I don't know how to do it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 -->
<html lang="en" class=""><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="file:///C:/Users/Glowing%20social%20icon%20hover%20effect_files/console_runner-ce3034e6bde3912cc25f83cccb7caa2b0f976196f2f2d52303a462c826d54a73.js.download"></script>
<script src="file:///C:/Users//Glowing%20social%20icon%20hover%20effect_files/css_live_reload_init-e9c0cc5bb634d3d14b840de051920ac153d7d3d36fb050abad285779d7e5e8bd.js.download"></script>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico"><link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111"><link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/cool_lazyboy/pen/qXeJOG">
<link href="./index_files/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style class="cp-pen-styles">* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
}

/* Let's style the wrapper in such away that, 
it should always be at the center of the browser */
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 550px;
}

/* Style the Un-order list by setting its list-style to none */
.wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Style the list items inside the UL list, by setting its width, height and line-height 
  and float them to left and set its border and border-radius.
 */
.wrapper ul li {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #D8E2DC;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Style the icons by setting its color and margin-top value to 20px 
to align it properly */
.wrapper ul li .fa {
  color: #D8E2DC;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


/* whatsapp */
.wrapper ul li:hover.whatsapp {
  border: 5px solid #4dc247;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4dc247;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li:hover .fa-whatsapp {
  color: #4dc247;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px #4dc247;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


/* media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .wrapper {
      width: 350px;
  }
  .wrapper ul li{
      margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .wrapper ul li.google{
      margin-left: 60px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 340px){
  .wrapper {
      width: 150px;
  }
  .wrapper ul li{
      margin:15px;
  }
  .wrapper ul li.google{
      margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

}</style></head>
<body>
<link href="file:///C:/Users/C/Videos/glowing/other%20one/fok%203a%20zebi/Glowing%20social%20icon%20hover%20effect_files/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="wrapper" id="myButton">
  <ul>
    <li class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" script type="text/javascript" ></i></li>

</script>
  </ul>
</div>


</body></html>
```

[REDIT] i want to change the aspect of the green simple whatsapp button to an glowing nice button....

Comment: So you want to change the css on the red button in the first example to the css on the whatsapp example?

Comment: Also please remove all the local sourced files from your example code

Comment: yes please can you mix it for me to include the first code(with popup chat ) on the second one

Comment: You mean the second in the first? I am confused.What is the end result the pizza code with a green glow?

Comment: yes i want to change the red button to the green glow whatsapp button to look more professional  ;)

Comment: like this one, but i want it glowing when you click on it

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.floatingWhatsApp = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            phone: '',
            message: '',
            size: '72px',
            backgroundColor: '#25D366',
            position: 'left',
            popupMessage: '',
            showPopup: false,
            showOnIE: true,
            autoOpenTimeout: 0,
            headerColor: '#128C7E',
            headerTitle: 'WhatsApp Chat',
            zIndex: 0,
            buttonImage: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 800 800" width="800" height="800"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_A3g8G5hPEGG2L0B6hFCxamU4cc8rfqzQ"><rect width="800" height="800"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_A3g8G5hPEGG2L0B6hFCxamU4cc8rfqzQ)"><g><path d=" M 787.59 800 L 12.41 800 C 5.556 800 0 793.332 0 785.108 L 0 14.892 C 0 6.667 5.556 0 12.41 0 L 787.59 0 C 794.444 0 800 6.667 800 14.892 L 800 785.108 C 800 793.332 794.444 800 787.59 800 Z " fill="rgb(37,211,102)"/></g><g><path d=" M 508.558 450.429 C 502.67 447.483 473.723 433.24 468.325 431.273 C 462.929 429.308 459.003 428.328 455.078 434.22 C 451.153 440.114 439.869 453.377 436.434 457.307 C 433 461.236 429.565 461.729 423.677 458.78 C 417.79 455.834 398.818 449.617 376.328 429.556 C 358.825 413.943 347.008 394.663 343.574 388.768 C 340.139 382.873 343.207 379.687 346.155 376.752 C 348.804 374.113 352.044 369.874 354.987 366.436 C 357.931 362.999 358.912 360.541 360.875 356.614 C 362.837 352.683 361.857 349.246 360.383 346.299 C 358.912 343.352 347.136 314.369 342.231 302.579 C 337.451 291.099 332.597 292.654 328.983 292.472 C 325.552 292.301 321.622 292.265 317.698 292.265 C 313.773 292.265 307.394 293.739 301.996 299.632 C 296.6 305.527 281.389 319.772 281.389 348.752 C 281.389 377.735 302.487 405.731 305.431 409.661 C 308.376 413.592 346.949 473.062 406.015 498.566 C 420.062 504.634 431.03 508.256 439.581 510.969 C 453.685 515.451 466.521 514.818 476.666 513.302 C 487.978 511.613 511.502 499.06 516.409 485.307 C 521.315 471.55 521.315 459.762 519.842 457.307 C 518.371 454.851 514.446 453.377 508.558 450.429 Z  M 401.126 597.117 L 401.047 597.117 C 365.902 597.104 331.431 587.661 301.36 569.817 L 294.208 565.572 L 220.08 585.017 L 239.866 512.743 L 235.21 505.332 C 215.604 474.149 205.248 438.108 205.264 401.1 C 205.307 293.113 293.17 205.257 401.204 205.257 C 453.518 205.275 502.693 225.674 539.673 262.696 C 576.651 299.716 597.004 348.925 596.983 401.258 C 596.939 509.254 509.078 597.117 401.126 597.117 Z  M 567.816 234.565 C 523.327 190.024 464.161 165.484 401.124 165.458 C 271.24 165.458 165.529 271.161 165.477 401.085 C 165.46 442.617 176.311 483.154 196.932 518.892 L 163.502 641 L 288.421 608.232 C 322.839 627.005 361.591 636.901 401.03 636.913 L 401.126 636.913 L 401.127 636.913 C 530.998 636.913 636.717 531.2 636.77 401.274 C 636.794 338.309 612.306 279.105 567.816 234.565" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"/></g></g></svg>',
        }, options);

        var isMobile = mobilecheck();

        //set the .floating-wpp default class
        this.addClass('floating-wpp');

        //#region jQuery Elements
        var $button = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $buttonImageContainer = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $popup = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $header = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $popupMessage = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $btnSend = $(document.createElement('div'));
        var $inputMessage = $(document.createElement('div'));
        //#endregion

        //#region Main Button
        $buttonImageContainer.addClass('floating-wpp-button-image');

        $button.addClass('floating-wpp-button')
            .append($(settings.buttonImage))
            .css({
                'width': settings.size,
                'height': settings.size,
                'background-color': settings.backgroundColor
            });

        if (!isInternetExplorer() || settings.showOnIE) {
            $button.append($buttonImageContainer).appendTo(this);
        }

        $button.on('click', function () {
            if (isMobile && settings.showPopup) {
                openPopup();
            }
            else {
                sendWhatsappMessage();
            }
        });
        //#endregion

        //#region Fake Chat Pop-up
        if (settings.showPopup) {
            var $textarea = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
            var $closeBtn = $(document.createElement('strong'));
            var $sendIcon = $('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 20 18" width="20" height="18"><defs><clipPath id="_clipPath_fgX00hLzP9PnAfCkGQoSPsYB7aEGkj1G"><rect width="20" height="18"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#_clipPath_fgX00hLzP9PnAfCkGQoSPsYB7aEGkj1G)"><path d=" M 0 0 L 0 7.813 L 16 9 L 0 10.188 L 0 18 L 20 9 L 0 0 Z " fill="rgb(46,46,46)"/></g></svg>')

            $popup.addClass('floating-wpp-popup');
            $header.addClass('floating-wpp-head');
            $popupMessage.addClass('floating-wpp-message');
            $inputMessage.addClass('floating-wpp-input-message');
            $btnSend.addClass('floating-wpp-btn-send');

            $popupMessage.text(settings.popupMessage);
            $textarea.val(settings.message);

            if (!settings.popupMessage) {
                $popupMessage.hide();
            }

            $header.append('<span>' + settings.headerTitle + '</span>', $closeBtn)
                .css('background-color', settings.headerColor);

            $btnSend.append($sendIcon);
            $inputMessage.append($textarea, $btnSend);

            $closeBtn.addClass('close').html('&times;');

            $popup.append(
                $header,
                $popupMessage,
                $inputMessage)
                .appendTo(this);

            $popupMessage.click(function () {
                //sendWhatsappMessage();
            });

            $closeBtn.click(function () {
                //popup.removeClass('active');
            });

            $header.click(function () {
                $popup.removeClass('active');
            });

            $textarea.keypress(function (event) {
                settings.message = $(this).val();

                if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey && !isMobile) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $btnSend.click();
                }
            });

            $btnSend.click(function () {
                settings.message = $textarea.val();
                sendWhatsappMessage();
            });

            this.mouseenter(function () {
                openPopup();
            });

            if (settings.autoOpenTimeout > 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    openPopup();
                }, settings.autoOpenTimeout);
            }

            function openPopup() {
                if (!$popup.hasClass('active')) {
                    $popup.addClass('active');
                    $textarea.focus();
                }
            }
        }

        if (settings.zIndex) {
            $(this).css('z-index', settings.zIndex);
        }

        if (settings.position === 'right') {
            this.css({
                left: 'auto',
                right: '15px'
            });
            $popup.css('right', '0');
        }
        //#endregion

        function sendWhatsappMessage() {
            var apilink = 'http://';

            apilink += isMobile ? 'api' : 'web';
            apilink += '.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + settings.phone + '&text=' + encodeURI(settings.message);

            window.open(apilink);
        }
    }

    function isInternetExplorer() {
        var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
        return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0 || userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
    }

    function mobilecheck() {
        var check = false;
        (function (a) { if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true; })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
        return check;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.floating-wpp {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: bottom 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.4);
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button img,
.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-button svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.floating-wpp:hover {
    bottom: 17px;
}

.floating-wpp:hover .floating-wpp-button {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.4);
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup {
    /*border: 2px solid white;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #E5DDD5;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.25);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: bottom 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup.active {
    padding: 0 12px 12px 12px;
    width: 260px;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 82px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup .floating-wpp-message {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup.active .floating-wpp-message {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-popup .floating-wpp-head {
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 -15px 10px -15px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-input-message {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px -15px -15px -15px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-input-message textarea {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    resize: none;
}

.floating-wpp .floating-wpp-btn-send {
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-size: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.floating-wpp-button:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px crimson !important;
    opacity:1;
    border:none !important;
}
.floating-wpp-button {
    transition:0.3s all;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Floating WhatsApp Button Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="floating-wpp.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="floating-wpp.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myButton"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myButton').floatingWhatsApp({
            phone: '5491133359850',
            popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?',
            message: "I'd like to order a pizza",
            showPopup: true,
            showOnIE: false,
            headerTitle: 'Welcome!',
            headerColor: 'crimson',
            backgroundColor: 'crimson',
            buttonImage: '<img src="burger.svg" />'
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just add below css and you're done...

```
.floating-wpp-button:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px crimson !important;
    opacity:1;
    border:none !important;
}
.floating-wpp-button {
    transition:0.3s all;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: But i  want the exactly same button white with green light based on fontawesome how i can do that ?